# Prove that $\sum^n_{i=1} X_i$ and $\prod^n_{i=1} X_i$ are sufficient statistics for the gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, functions, gamma-distribution, sufficient-statistics

This question is set in the statistical context, but my difficulty is more ‘pure math’ in nature, so I have posted it here instead of at the statistics forum.

I am to prove that $V := \sum^n_{i=1} X_i$ and $W := \prod^n_{i=1} X_i$ are sufficient statistics from the gamma distribution.

By the factorisation theorem, if the joint pdf of a series of random variables $\vec{X} := (X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ can be factorised in such a manner:

$$f(\vec{X}|\theta) = g(T(\vec{X}), \theta)\;h(\vec{X})$$

where $T(\vec{X})$ is the statistic; then $T(\vec{X})$ is a sufficient statistic for the series of random variables $\vec{X}$.

---

I have expressed the joint distribution of iid gamma variables as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
  f(\vec{X}|\alpha, \lambda) &= \prod^n_{i=1} f(X_i|\alpha, \lambda) \\
    &= \lambda^{n\alpha}\;\Gamma(\alpha)^{-n}\;W^{\alpha-1}\;e^{-\lambda V}
\end{align*}$$

Clearly, for the statistic $T(\vec{X}) = V$, the factorised form has $g(T(\vec{X}), \alpha, \lambda) = \lambda^{n\alpha}\; \Gamma(\alpha)^n\; e^{-\lambda V}$. In a similar fashion, the statistic $T(\vec{X}) = V$ has $g(T(\vec{X}), \alpha, \lambda) = \lambda^{n\alpha}\; \Gamma(\alpha)^n\; W^{\alpha-1}$.

But I cannot figure out how the last term can be expressed as just $h(\vec{X})$. For the former statistic $V$, the remaining term is $W^{\alpha-1}$, which depends on $\alpha$; the latter $W$ has the remaining term $e^{-\lambda V}$, which depends on $\lambda$. Yet I know for certain (from literature) that both $W$ and $V$ are indeed sufficient statistics.

Obviously, I must have some misconception here. Can someone correct me, please?

Comment: If $\theta=(\alpha,\lambda)$ is the unknown parameter, then from factorisation theorem you can only say that $(\prod X_i,\sum X_i)$ is (jointly) sufficient for $\theta$. Not that $\prod X_i$ is sufficient for $\alpha$ and $\sum X_i$ is sufficient for $\lambda$. As for $h(X)$, it would be clear once you include the support of the density (i.e. using indicator functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf is $f(x|\alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha) \beta^\alpha} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}} \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ : then the joint density is
$$
f(\underline{X}|\alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)^n \beta^{n\alpha}} W^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{V}{\beta}} \prod_{i=1}^n \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x_i)
$$
and you have the factorised form. Note that (V,W) are jointly sufficient, but not on their own.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed it

Comment: @franzk Thank you. My misunderstanding was assuming that the two statistics are each, on their own, sufficient. The important clarification which you have provided is that this is wrong—they are only *jointly* sufficient.